# openGL reverse image texturing logic

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, projection

I'm about to project image into cylindrical panorama. But first I need to get the pixel (or color from pixel) I'm going to draw, then then do some Math in shaders with polar coordinates to get new position of pixel and then finally draw pixel.

Using this way I'll be able to change shape of image from polygon shape to whatever I want.

But I cannot find anything about this method (get pixel first, then do the Math and get new position for pixel).
Is there something like this, please?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL historically doesn't work that way around; it forward renders — from geometry to pixels — rather than backwards — from pixel to geometry.

The most natural way to achieve what you want to do is to calculate texture coordinates based on geometry, then render as usual. For a cylindrical mapping:

- establish a mapping from cylindrical coordinates to texture coordinates;
- with your actual geometry, imagine it placed within the cylinder, then from each vertex proceed along the normal until you intersect the cylinder. Use that location to determine the texture coordinate for the original vertex.

The latter is most easily and conveniently done within your geometry shader; it's a simple ray intersection test, with attributes therefore being only vertex location and vertex normal, and texture location being a varying that is calculated purely from the location and normal.

Extemporaneously, something like:

```
// get intersection as if ray hits the circular region of the cylinder,
// i.e. where |(position + n*normal).xy| = 1
float planarLengthOfPosition = length(position.xy);
float planarLengthOfNormal = length(normal.xy);
float planarDistanceToPerimeter = 1.0 - planarLengthOfNormal;
vec3 circularIntersection = position + 
                            (planarDistanceToPerimeter/planarLengthOfNormal)*normal;

// get intersection as if ray hits the bottom or top of the cylinder,
// i.e. where |(position + n*normal).z| = 1
float linearLengthOfPosition = abs(position.z);
float linearLengthOfNormal = abs(normal.z);
float linearDistanceToEdge = 1.0 - linearLengthOfPosition;
vec3 endIntersection = position +
                       (linearDistanceToEdge/linearLengthOfNormal)*normal;

// pick whichever of those was lesser
vec3 cylindricalIntersection = mix(circularIntersection,
                                   endIntersection,
                                   step(linearDistanceToEdge, 
                                        planarDistanceToPerimeter));

// ... do something to map cylindrical intersection to texture coordinates ...
textureCoordinateVarying = 
    coordinateFromCylindricalPosition(cylindricalIntersection);
```

With a common implementation of `coordinateFromCylindricalPosition` possibly being simply `return vec2(atan(cylindricalIntersection.y, cylindricalIntersection.x) / 6.28318530717959, cylindricalIntersection.z * 0.5);`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, but I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to tell me. In the first bullet shouldn't I first establish mapping from texture coordinates to cylindrical? And what exactly represent position and normal mentioned in code?

Comment: Without subversion, in WebGL rendering involves (i) establishing some constants; (ii) specifying some geometry; (iii) via a user-supplied function, mapping that geometry to window coordinates and establishing interpolated values; and (iv) via another user-supplied function, mapping the interpolated values to colours for every pixel. From geometry to pixels, not vice versa. So I've suggested how you can use that pipeline to produce a cylindrical projection rather than fighting it. Position and normal are just the position and the normal of each vertex in your geometry.

Comment: ... it is possible to subvert, e.g. by writing what amounts to a ray tracer in a shader but it's not likely to perform well and should be a plan of last resort, especially in the constrained shading language of WebGL.